# Spring boot configuration properties issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

I have been working on creating a custom data source bean. The code and .properties file is below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EnableWebMvc
public class ConfigClass {

    @Bean(name="DbDataSource", destroyMethod="close")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="db.datasource")
    public DataSource dbDataSource() {
        DataSource ds;
        ds = DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        return  ds;
    }
    @Bean(name = "taxTransactionManager")
    public JpaTransactionManager getJpaTransactionManager(){
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setDataSource(dbDataSource());
    }
```

=======================================================================

```
#db datasource
db.datasource.type=javax.sql.DataSource
db.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

The problem is it doesn't seem to be loading/applying the properties to the data source bean because I keep getting the following error:

```
The persistence provider is attempting to use properties in the persistence.xml file to resolve the data source. A Java Database Connectivity (JDBC) driver or data source class name must be specified in the openjpa.ConnectionDriverName or javax.persistence.jdbc.driver property. The following properties are available in the configuration: "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl@982e6a52". 
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.DataSourceFactory.newDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:72)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.createConnectionFactory(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:849)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.getConnectionFactory(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:732)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor47.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
```

I have tried putting the configuration in all one file and I have also tried using separate files and referencing one config file in another as shown below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class ConfigClass {
    @Bean(name="dbDataSource", destroyMethod="close")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="posdb.datasource")
    public DataSource dbDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }}
```

========================================================

```
@Configuration
@Import(ConfigClass.class)
public class ConfigClass2{

@Autowired
ConfigClass config1;

        @Bean(name = "genericTransactionManager")
        public JpaTransactionManager getJpaTransactionManager(){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setDataSource(config1.dbDataSource());
        return transactionManager;
    }}
```

The config class is being imported to configure and run my application below:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
    SessionAutoConfiguration.class,DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
    JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class,JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration.class,
    RedisAutoConfiguration.class})
@Import(ConfigClass.class)
public class ServiceBootstrap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceBootstrap.class, args);
    }
}
```

The spring boot app is in another project and the config class is being imported making this a dependency project. I have also tried to import my ConfigClass2 in the ServiceBootstrap class and I am still getting the same error. Also I tried to autowire the data source bean itself instead of the config class and the bean came back as null. Does anyone know what may be causing this problem?

Comment: Have you tried autowiring `dbDataSource` instead of `ConfigClass` in `ConfigClass2`. And maybe, use `@Qualifier` when autowiring.

Comment: Also what happens when you add `@EnableTransactionManagement` to `ConfigClass2` class?

Comment: Also I am not using any of the auto config classes